# Convert char cr to int

Tags: arduino

Im reading a text in the SD card. Here is the code:

```
void Readline(){
  myFile.seek(0);
  char cr;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 0;){
    cr = myFile.read();
    if(cr == '\n')
      {
        i++;
      }
  }
  while(true){
    cr = myFile.read();
    if((cr == '\n')||(cr == '\r')||(cr < 0))
    break;
    Serial.println(cr);
  }
}
```

How can I convert the char 'cr' to integer?

Comment: This question is incomplete: do you want to convert `'9'` to `57` or `9`? Also, do you want to handle subsequent digits, e.g. `13`, as separate values or a single one?

Comment: The value written in the SD card is 6.25 char type. How can I read the value and convert it into float type as a single value?

Comment: Then your question is malformed: `6.25` is not *char type* and the title says `int` and not `float`. You should break down your task. First: get a string containing `6.25`, either of type `char*` or `String`, Second: convert such string into `float`.

Comment: Sir give me a sample of that code Im new to these. Im finding it very hard to understand. II just found that code from the internet.

Answer (score -1):

Just try with cr.toInt();

The .toInt() command converts Strings to integers

For more info look here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringToIntExample

Comment: request for member 'toInt' in 'cr', which is of non-class type 'char'

Comment: It gives me that message

Comment: or how can I convert char to String?

Comment: `cr` is a `char` not a `String`.